# validateObservable in Knockout JS - undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-validation

Good day,

I am trying to validate a pretty huge form on my side, and basically rewritten all of my viewModel code so it can be validated. Problem is that ko.validatedObservable() doesn't seem to exist for some reason. I have used the code from [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424641/Customer-KnockoutJS-Validation), and I honestly cannot see what's the problem in my code. Here is a sample:

```
var someNameSpace= {};

    someNameSpace.bindData = function () {
        someNameSpace.viewModel =
        someNameSpace.initViewModel("123456", "username1", "address1", "address2", "city");

        ko.applyBindings(this.viewModel);
    }

someNameSpace.initViewModel = function (partnerId, username, address1, address2, city) {
    console.log(ko);
    var someViewModel = ko.validatedObservable({ //<----FAILS HERE
        partnerId: ko.observable(partnerId).extend({ required: "This field is required", number: true }),
        username: ko.observable(username).extend({ required: "This field is required" }),
        address1: ko.observable(address1).extend({ required: "This field is required" }),
        address2: ko.observable(address2).extend({ required: "This field is required" }),
        city: ko.observable(city).extend({ required: "This field is required" }),
    });

    var validationOptions = { insertMessages: true, decorateElement: true };
    ko.validation.init(validationOptions);

    return someViewModel ;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    someNamespace.bindData();
});
```

On that site, it claims to use the ko.validatedObservable in order to inspect whether or not fields were correctly entered by the user. I am still very new to knockoutJS - what can I do?

[image: error]

Comment: There's too much to read, can you reproduce in jsfiddle?

Comment: haha, ok I will shorten the code. its literally only ko.validatedObservable that fails. Its way too much code to quickly reproduce in fiddle - this is merely a sample from a file which is way over 800 lines of code :/

Comment: See? You'll more responses this way I reckon.

Comment: part of my life :P scolded every day of my life for giving away too much info

Comment: Life's a bitch. On top of it all I know f** all about knockout, so don't expect an answer from me :)

Comment: @Noobgrammer Have you included the reference to the 'knockout.validation.js' library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include a reference to the `'knockout.validation.js'` library.

**knockout.validation.js**

https://rawgit.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/master/Src/knockout.validation.js

**GitHub reference**

https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

Comment: That hits the spot. I went through our last commit from a junior dev that "cleaned up" the project. lo-and-behold. He removed knockout.validation.js. Thank you.

Comment: @Noobgrammer Nice one, cakes are on him. :)

Comment: He is in trouble, that much I can say - though I am not authorized to rasp him :P